# simple jquery script in inline PrettyPhoto box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I've a problem with prettyphoto and a simple jquery script in a PrettyPhoto inline box.
Why I can't hide the div in this prettyphoto box? I don't understand why this is not working...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pretty photo test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <li><a href="#inline_demo" rel="prettyPhoto[inline]">Inline content 1</a></li>

        <div id="inline_demo" style="display:none;">
          <div id="testje" style="display:block">this is a test</div>
          <a onclick="$('#testje').hide(); return false">Close test div</a>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
            });
        </script>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you want to hide an element that isn't displayed?!

Comment: Thanks Skalar, i've changed the example script, but my problem isn't over....

Comment: now if I click on the text "Close test div", the "this is a test" becomes hidden

Answer (score 1):

No need to add `[inline]` :

```
<li><a href="#inline_demo" rel="prettyPhoto">Inline content 1</a></li>

<div id="inline_demo" style="display:none;">
  <div id="testje">this is a test</div>
  <a onclick="$('#testje').hide(); return false;">Close test div</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but that isn't my problem. The problem is de little show/hide script in the box...

Comment: Maybe you're including a script or css wrong, or something else... Show us your whole html file.